# How can I pass in multiple data sources into an XSLT mediator in WSO2 ESB

Tags: xslt, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have tried to pass in multiple nodesets into an XSLT in the XSLT mediator in WSO2 ESB through parameters to the stylesheet. However when trying to refer to the parameters passed in the XSLT processor says that the values are string types.

The XSLT mediator config itself is structured like this:

```
<xslt key="conf:/Test/TestMapping.xsl">
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="originalMsg" expression="get-property('OriginalMsg')" />
   </xslt>
```

In the XSLT itself when the passed parameter is used to try to refer to an element in this data, e.g.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$originalMsg/ns1:Node/ns1:OtherNode"/>
```

the error reports that "/" operation cannot be applied to a string when it expects a nodeset.

I have tried to pass on the nodeset which is the mesage body from a previous step in the flow, which I have tried various medthods to save:

Through Enrich mediator:

```
<enrich>
<source clone="true" type="body" xpath="" property="" />
<target action="replace" type="property" xpath="" property="OriginalMsg" />
</enrich>
```

Through Property mediator:

```
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="OriginalMsg" expression="$body" scope="default" type="OM" />
```

But this has not worked.

Alternatively, is there a way to use document() in the ESB function to refer to message context data or some other approach?

Comment: What version of XSLT does WS02 support? I suspect it's version 1. In version 1 you can't apply XPath expression to variables. You may be able to use extensions such as EXSLT's node-set which turns a string variable into a node set. It may be more productive though if you can see if you can persuade WS02 to use an XSLT 2 engine such as Saxon as XSLT version 2 removes lots of annoying restrictions imposed by version 1

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this issue by adding the additional XML data hierarchies that I needed to include as siblings to the current root element within the message body, with the Enrich mediator.

This allowed all the different data to be available in the XSLT.

Then in XSLT mediator configuration I set the source path to $body (i.e. the message body) rather than the default value (which is the first child of message body) and added a SOAP Body element as root element in the XSLT itself. In this way all the children of the message body were replaced with the single target XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the XSLT mediator code:

```
 private void  applyProperties(Transformer transformer, MessageContext synCtx, SynapseLog synLog) {

    for (MediatorProperty prop : properties) {
        if (prop != null) {
            String value;
            if (prop.getValue() != null) {
                value = prop.getValue();
            } else {
                value = prop.getExpression().stringValueOf(synCtx);
            }
            if (synLog.isTraceOrDebugEnabled()) {
                if (value == null) {
                    synLog.traceOrDebug("Not setting parameter '" + prop.getName() + "'");
                } else {
                    synLog.traceOrDebug("Setting parameter '" + prop.getName() + "' to '"
                            + value + "'");
                }
            }
            if (value != null) {
                transformer.setParameter(prop.getName(), value);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can see that **value** is always a String. I propose to add for the properties the type of the property before injecting in the transformer.

What do you think?